# "Error in model.matrix.formula(form, data) : data must be a data.frame" while doing a GAM (mgcv package) in R

Tags: r, nested, gam, mgcv

**Asking for a friendly soul that knows how to fix this error or that understands why this is appearing.**

Not exactly sure what happened but this error appears every time I try to do a GAM with random effects (`bs="re"`, with `mgcv` package). This is strange since appears not only to new models but even to models that previously worked (multiple times).
I made sure the data has no NA's, scientific data, or random formulas. Also, I am not using the date format to avoid errors has previously worked as it is.

I also tried to transform the data into a data frame via `as.data.frame(x)` but the same error occurred.

I have been playing a bit with the formula and it appears that every time the random effects `bs="re"` are present, either the 2 of them (Site, State) or only one of them (Site), it is when the error occurs. If I take them completely out of the formula it works perfectly.

**I am thinking that could be:**

1. Some incompatibility with another package that I may have installed but tried to solve this with no effect. Removed all the most recently installed packages and the error persisted.
2. Other could be any update to the `mgcv` package?

Update: It works in R software just not in R studio.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this or why this is appearing

**The following model was previously working but not anymore, giving me every single time the mentioned error**

`gam_2a <- gam(Total_Items ~ s(DayI0, k=14) + s(Site, State, bs="re"), offset(log(EffortDayC)),data = x,family=poisson(link="log"),method = "REML")`

**Description of the variables:**

Total_Items = Number of items of debris found per event;

DayI0 = Number of days since first clean up (numeric);

Site = Site of sampling (Sites are within States);

State = State of sampling;

EffortDayC = Effort(Length of the beach, number of volunteers, duration of sampling)*DayC(interval of sampling);

**The str(x) output below:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul5KV.png)

**And the head of the data to understand a bit better:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep45Y.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHEl9.png)

Comment: It would be better if you can create a reproducible example so that people can diagnose it for themselves. Also don't post pictures of code/output. The system is designed to display and format actual code/output.

Answer (score 2):

Sorted! the package `agricolae` was causing some incompatibility with the `mgcv` package.